# Writing an activerecord statement to query a datetime column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a profiles table with a column name videoconfavailability which is a datetime type. I am trying to make an Ajax button_tag to search all of the videoconfavailability 1 hour from Time.now and 1 hour before Time.now.
so far I have this line here, is there a NOT clause to filter out other conditions?

```
Profile.where("videoconfavailability <= ? AND videoconfavailability >= ?", Time.now + 1.hour , Time.now - 1.hour )
```

The end goal here is to have ALL of the time available 1 hour before current time and 1 hour after current time.
Is this going to work?

Comment: can I make a fancy scope or lamda or class method with this?

Comment: first question... Have you tried this? if so let us know what the output was. Secondly, yes you can methodise this but before moving onto that let us know what you have tried please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me - maybe you can explain the issue you are having with it!

In terms of using it you might consider creating a scope tied to your `Profile` model. If you need to use it with different time ranges perhaps it could accept `arguments`. If not then just hardcode it to make it easier to use again and again with repeating yourself.

```
scope :available_within_time, -> (start, end) { where("videoconfavailability <= ? AND videoconfavailability >= ?", start, end )
```

As it's written in your question perhaps consider making use of the Rails time helpers to make things even more concise.

```
1.hour.ago
1.hour.from_now
```

If you want to filter out negative matches to check some other condition you can chain a `.where.not(QUERY)` onto your existing query.